# Ringtone played in Airtel boss Ad

Tags: ringtones

In the Airtel boss ad, when the husband receives a video message from his boss wife, a ringtone of a second or a two is played. What is the name of that ringtone? I suppose it belongs to the Iphone only.

https://youtu.be/qOetR_5leT4

Comment: Yes exactly, I want this ringtone only! Can you please name it?

Comment: Now that we can hear it, someone might find it :)

Comment: Well lets hope, I badly need that ringtone. Please tell me if you find it.

Comment: how badly? as bad as you would go true the process of creating it ? https://blog.udemy.com/how-to-add-ringtones-to-iphone/

Comment: Better I get the name just of the ringtone. Rest I'll do.

Answer (score 1):

It's an alert tone (not a ringtone) and it's called Aurora.

[image: Aurora alert tone]